# The @propery tag in the class description breaks doc file

Tags: php, doxygen, phpdoc

I am trying to document php project using doxygen and have a problem.

In the project that I am working on, developers often use the @property tag. PHPDoc supports it and calls it the ["Magic" property](https://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.property.pkg.html). However Doxygen does not generate documentation for classes with this tag.

For example:

```
<?php
/**
 *  Brief description.
 *
 * @property BarClass $bar <<<< this line causes the problem
 */
abstract class Foo
{
    protected $bar;
}
```

When I remove the problem line, doxygen generates documentation as expected. But when the @property tag is in the description, doxygen does not parse any comments from the file.

Doxygen log contains warning about each declaration:

> documented symbol 'BarClass $bar' was not declared or defined.

But all information about this warning that I've found in the web is about C and I could not apply that solutions to PHP.

Is it possible to solve the problem without deleting all the problem tags?

Comment: Which version of dixygen are you using? Where did you define / document the type `BarClass`

Comment: I am using Doxygen v 1.9.5. Classes are defined in separate php files. Not all of them have documentation now.

Comment: Looks like there is a discrepancy between the doxygen definition of `@property` (see https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdproperty), probably best is to define an `ALIASES` setting (see https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_aliases) for this like `ALIASES += property=`

Comment: It seems you are right. I added property to the ALIASES and Doxygen started to parse files. Thanks!